# Unable to import images from different folder in React Naitve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi all I'm new to react native and unable to display images from different folder. Here is my image file structure.

```
src/images/bell.png
src/images/images.js
```

images.js

```
export const NOTIFICATION_ICON = require('./bell.png');
```

The file structure of the component I'm using this image

```
src/components/common/AppHeader.js
```

My AppHeader.js file

```
import { NOTIFICATION_ICON } from "../../images/images";

 return(
    <Image source={NOTIFICATION_ICON} />
 );
```

I'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Does it work when you directly require the image from the source prop?

Comment: No, it still displays the same error

Answer (score 1):

remove curly braces and try

```
import NOTIFICATION_ICON from "../../images/images";
```

Comment: It displays the following error in this case Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: It got resolved. The issue was with the Image tag. I imported Image from naitve-base instead of react-native. That's causing the issue.

Comment: Ok Good to know. Happy coding